# Do I have to use guns to achieve A+ scores in Hotline Miami 2?

Tags: hotline-miami-2

It definitely seems off for me for the sequel, in which I seemingly have to rely on guns to achieve A+ scores.   In Hotline Miami 1 it was simple getting A+ scores with melees or fists, but  Hotline Miami 2 seems to have much more emphasis on guns over fists.

Is it possible to even get an A+ score with melees/fists? I've been trying over an hour or so and the closest I've come is a B average on most levels.

Do I have no choice but to bring guns?

Comment: Did you manage to get A+ with guns, or are you just speculating?

Comment: @npst If you've played the game you'll know exactly what I"m talking about. By the looks of it, you haven't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the first few levels it's possible, but you'll need to start using them eventually if you want A+.  It's all about keeping the combo up and using a variety of different weapons.